# spark streaming job performance improvement

Tags: python, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming

There is a spark streaming job running all the time, counting words in the stream, and only the words in a given vocabulary should be counted and returned.

However, this vocabulary is not fixed, instead the vocabulary is stored in `redis` and can change over time. Here is a naive implementation of this job:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="WordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)  # batch interval is 10s

def check_if_in_vocab(word):
    vocab = redis_client.smembers()  # get all vocabulary from redis
    return word in vocab

lines = ssc.socketTextStream(host_ip, port)  # read data stream from the socket
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
                          .filter(check_if_in_vocab)\  # ANY BETTER SOLUTION HERE??? 
                          .map(lambda word: (word, 1))  # create (word, count) pair
counts = words.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
counts.pprint()
```

My implementation has poor performance I think, because the `filter(check_if_in_vocabulary)` transformation pull the vocabulary from redis for each element in the stream, that would be too time consuming.

Any better solution?

**FOLLOWUP**

OK, in the above problem, since the vocabulary might change any time, so I need to check `redis` very often, now suppose the vocabulary only changes every 60sec or 1h, would it be simpler to improve the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with Spark in Python, but if this were a Scala implementation, I would look for improvements by making my Redis call inside a `mapPartitions` call. Inside `mapPartitions`, I would establish a connection with the client, fetch the `vocab`, use that in-memory `vocab` to filter the iterable, and then close the connection.

Perhaps you can do something analogous with the Python API.

Comment: yes, indeed I could use mapPartitions in python too, but  I have another concern that, as I read in the doc of mapPartitions, it will run the data preparation code (which is to pull down the vocabulary from redis here in my case) only ONCE for that partition, but my situation is the vocabulary might change over time, so that means for each partition, I need to be able to update the vocabulary over time, running the redis code only ONCE won't do that, am I right?